# What's the translation of “staff research scientist" in French?

Tags: traduction

I am trying to translate from English to French different researcher positions:

- Research scientist = Chercheur.
- Senior research scientist = Chercheur [senior](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/senior/72074).
- Principal scientist = Chercheur principal.
- [Staff research scientist](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/163493/452) = ?

What's the translation of “staff research scientist" in French?

See [Usage of staff as a seniority level (“staff engineer”)](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/563389/17712) and [meaning of “staff” in the title “senior staff software engineer”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/10301/3023) for the use of *staff* in English.

---

My research:

1. Google Translate and [Linguee](https://www.linguee.com/english-french/search?source=auto&query=Staff+research+scientist) did not help.

Comment: Déjà que le terme n'est pas très standardisé en anglais, je doute qu'il y ait une traduction non ambigüe. Je n'ai jamais vu « principal » utilisé dans ce sens en français non plus, alors que *principal* en anglais est un peu plus courant. Le [GDT](http://gdt.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/ficheOqlf.aspx?Id_Fiche=8870902) a une fiche qui propose « principal » comme traduction de « *senior* »…

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' thanks, in some places they have principal, senior and staff scientists, so I was interested in having some French terms that could distinguish these two positions. Senior, principal and staff are very common in the Bay Area, California at least.

Comment: I've asked about the English usage [on English Usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563389/usage-of-staff-as-a-seniority-level-staff-engineer).

Comment: @Gilles'SOnousesthostile' Thanks very much, great question!

Comment: Wikipedia peut aider: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Academic_ranks_in_France

De mon point de vue, "senior" veur dire "agé". Alors que dans ce cas c'est experimenté, ceci dit les anglicismes sont de plus en plus présents dans le francais.
Est-ce que Staff research scientist est plus "experimenté" que "principal"?
Je pense qu'en France et en particulier dans le fonctionariat les echelles d'anciennetées sont beaucoup plus complexes. Alors que dans beaucoup de metier dans les pays anglox-saxon c'est plus junior," ", senior, principal, senior principal.

Answer (score -2):

I would translate it as

> membre de la recherche scientifique

Comment: thank you, doesn't équipe  implies that this is a team instead of an individual researcher?  (Staff research scientist is an individual researcher not a team)

Comment: Take a look at my updated answer

Comment: Thank you!~~~~~

Comment: C'est un contresens. *Staff*, utilisé comme adjectif dans un titre, est un grade au-dessus de *senior* et au-dessous de *principal*. C'est utilisé dans certaines sociétés, surtout pour des ingénieurs. Voir par exemple https://www.reddit.com/r/AskEngineers/comments/2572oy/in_general_or_in_your_company_how_do_you_rank/, https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/46366/what-is-the-difference-between-these-senior-software-engineer-titles/46372 . Le terme n'est pas très connu, l'anglophone moyen ne le comprend pas.

Comment: @AmandeAdorable Ça n'a pas l'air connu des dictionnaires, mais j'ai rencontré le même sens que Franck. https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/563389/usage-of-staff-as-a-seniority-level-staff-engineer